# Am stuck at running gradle task "assembledebug"

Tags: flutter

This is my flutter doctor summary

> flutter doctor
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572], locale en-KE)
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
> [!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
> X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
> X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
> [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.51.0)
> [√] Connected device (1 available)

Comment: What is the output of the assemble build ?

Comment: Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)".  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)

Comment: Are you sure you have stable internet connection with good speed ?

Comment: Rebooted my internet connection and was in place to do it.Fixed it all pap.Thanks @ikerfah

Answer (score 0):

it says here:

X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.

So go to plugins and search for flutter plugin and click install, this will also install the dart plugin. then run flutter doctor again and everything should be fine

Comment: I have both the flutter and dart sdk plugins installed even in visual studio but this problem still persists

Comment: If you are facing this output from running Flutter Doctor, then they are probably not installed correctly, try uninstalling the 2 plugins and re-install them